# recieving a custom response from passportjs via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, passport.js

The scenario happens when I have the user in the DB but he has not yet defined a password, but this could benefit many more cases

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

routes.js :

```
app.post('/auth/signin', passport.authenticate('email'), user.authCallback);
```

//authCallback not reached so logic can't be here

passport.js:

```
    //Use local strategy
passport.use('email',new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({
            email: email
        }, function(err, user) {
            //no password (yet)
            if (!user.password){
                done(null, false, { message: 'no password' });
            }
        });
    }
));
```

client side:

```
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, more, more2 ) {
          $("#form-message").html(jqXHR+" - "+textStatus+" - "+more+" - "+more2 ).slideDown()
                    //returns
                    //[object Object] - error - - undefined
        });
```

Comment: possible solution: https://gist.github.com/cultofmetatron/5349630 but I think there should be a simpler way..

Comment: It actually makes sense to me to return `done(err)` from your strategy when the user doesn't have a password set. It's an error condition, the callback should represent it as such. It also simplifies your architecture.